# Iterate through period of time with query and insert into other table

Tags: sql, loops

I have a query that is currently hardcoded but needs to be replaced with the local variables (year and month). Furthermore it needs to iterate through a period (from January 2010 to March 2012 month by month) by using the variables.

Each result set needs to be inserted into a table and a timestamp for the corresponding months needs to inserted in the column (Period).

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            b.AccountInfo2  
            ,SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN EntryTypeNr=1520 THEN -Amount END,0)) SumTotal1
            ,SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN EntryTypeNr IN (1521,1522,1523) THEN -Amount END,0)) SumTotal2
            ,Description
FROM        AccountEntry a 
INNER JOIN  AccountBalance b ON a.AccountId = b.AccountId
AND         a.AccountSubTypeNr = b.AccountSubTypeNr  
WHERE       (YEAR(a.ValueDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()) **@Variable1**) AND
            (MONTH(a.ValueDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) **@Variable2**) AND
            (a.EntryTypeNr IN (1520, 1521, 1522, 1523)) AND
            AccountInfo2<>''
GROUP BY    AccountInfo2,Description
```

The table the results sets should be inserted into has the following columns:

- Period datetime
- AccountInfo2 varchar(50)
- SumTotal1 float
- SumTotal2 float
- Description varchar(50)

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a code request, not a question.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this question is about generating the months.  You can do this with a recursive CTE (the syntax looks like SQL Server)

```
with dates as (
      select cast('2010-01-01' as date) as month_start
      union all
      select dateadd(month, month_start, 1)
      from dates
      where month_start <= '2012-03-01'
     )
SELECT month_start, dateadd(month, 1, month_start) as month_end,
       b.AccountInfo2,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN EntryTypeNr  =1520 THEN -Amount ELSE 0 END) as SumTotal1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EntryTypeNr IN (1521, 1522, 1523) THEN -Amount ELSE 0 END) as SumTotal2,
       Description
FROM AccountEntry a INNER JOIN 
     AccountBalance b
     ON a.AccountId = b.AccountId AND
     a.AccountSubTypeNr = b.AccountSubTypeNr join
     dates
     on YEAR(a.ValueDate) = YEAR(dates.month_start) AND
        MONTH(a.ValueDate) = MONTH(dates.month_start)
WHERE (a.EntryTypeNr IN (1520, 1521, 1522, 1523)) AND
      AccountInfo2 <> ''
GROUP BY dates.month_start, AccountInfo2, Description ;
```

You can put this into a table by using `insert` or the `into` clause.  This solves the main problem, which is generating the series of values.